# Mapping a custom domain route to an application in App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, create-react-app

I have a custom domain with a route that I'd like to map to my React application (create-react-app production build being served on App engine). When I map the custom domain, none of my static files are found however. I've tried updating the handlers for the app but I'm getting the same error (404 on loading css, js, manifest). My `dispatch.yaml` is

```
dispatch:
  - url: "example.service.org/test"
    service:  my-service
```

Accessing `example.service.org/test` correctly populates the page title but none of the assets load. How do I update my handlers to serve the files correctly?

Comment: can you share your app.yaml? for example your static files are stored on this hypothetical link "example.service.org/static" and your main endpoint is "example.service.org/test"

Comment: on the appspot domain, is your application run as is expected?

Comment: @JAHDZP i don't have any specific handlers on my app.yaml, just the runtime and service name. everything works on the appspot domain.

Comment: What is the expected full URL of a static file?  "example.service.org/static/some.jpg" or "example.service.org/test/static/some.jpg"

Comment: @JAHDZP my guess is the latter "example.service.org/test/static/some.jpg" but neither is found on the server with the current configuration. do i need to update the paths in the build process?

Answer (score 0):

If this is working in your appspot.com domain means that your static routes works fine.

I think that the issue is caused because your service doesn't know how to address this path

`/test/static`

I think that are multiple solutions to this issue:

1.- Map the domain with the service without /test

```
dispatch:
  - url: "example.service.org"
    service:  my-service
```

with this workaround if you need a test url you can add an test subdomain in order to have 2 services one in prod and another in dev/test for example

```
dispatch:
  - url: "example.service.org"
    service:  my-service

  - url: "test.example.service.org"
    service:  test-my-service
```

2.- define in your app.yaml this handlers

```
handlers:
  - url: /static
    static_dir: static/

  - url: /test/static
    static_dir: static/
```